# MySQL - Searching a field twice

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have this MySQL table:

[image: SQL]

OK.. see the `type` field? Type `0` is when a person KNOWS and a language and Type `1` is when a person is LEARNING that language.

and let's say I have some data:

[image]

As you can see, member `3` corresponds with `uid` (user id). User `3` KNOWS Chinese because of the type `0` but where was User `1` is LEARNING Chinese because of the type `1`.

And finally, let's say I make a form. It has two `select` fields filled with an array of language selections. After a certain submit... `$lang_learning` outputs `zh` and `$language_know` outputs `en`. How would I find a person who speaks `zh` and is learning `en` without conflicting with the `language` field since you're essentially looking for it twice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a self join. Try this.

```
SELECT t1.uid 
FROM languages t1
INNER JOIN languages t2 ON t1.uid = t2.uid
WHERE t1.language = 'zh' AND t1.type = 0
  AND t2.language = 'en' AND t2.type = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with a simple query, as standard 'where' clauses consider records row-by-row. Simple queries cannot do "select a record where field X is 'a' in one record and field X is 'b' in another.

For this, you'd need a join:

```
SELECT knows.uid
FROM yourtable AS knows
INNER JOIN yourtable AS learning ON knows.uid = learning.uid
WHERE (knows.language='zh' AND knows.type=0) AND (learning.language='en' AND knows.type=1)
```